# XAML Designer event handling

Tags: c#, wpf, events, custom-controls, xaml-designer

I have my custom [`UserControl`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/system.windows.controls.usercontrol(v=vs.110).aspx) (`ScaleTest`) in which I set some nested properties like this:

```
<local:ScaleTest Some="1">
    <local:ScaleTest.scals>
        <s:Scales step="15"></s:Scales>
        <s:Scales step="10"></s:Scales>
        <s:Scales step="30" color="Red"></s:Scales>
    </local:ScaleTest.scals>
</local:ScaleTest>
```

My controls draws some graphics based on that data and my problem is that changing those nested properties won't cause the designer view (or my control) to update until I rebuild my project.
The change of `step` for example will not cause the update but when change `Some` the view is redraw using new `step` value.

I use events to inform `ScaleTest` about the change of one of scales property.

```
private List<Scales> _scals = new List<Scales>();
public List<Scales> scals {
    get => _scals;
    set {
        _scals = value;
        foreach (var s in _scals) {
            s.STEP_CHANGE += onStepChange;
        }
        drawGrid(gr);
    }
}

private void onStepChange(ScaleEvent e) {
    drawGrid(gr);
}

private double sg;
public double Some {
    get => sg;
    set { sg = value;
        drawGrid(gr);
    }
}
```

I'm not sure if the designer supports events handling or I need to do something more or it's a bug. I have other issues with designer recently, even with simplest examples. For example I have

> Error     A value of type 'Scales' cannot be added to a collection or
>   dictionary of type 'List'.

While it renders correctly. I cant live with it, sometimes it goes away by itself but again, my short question is

**Does XAML Designer support events?**

Comment: The answer to your question is _yes_.  However, it is best that it is driven by INotifyPropertyChanged

Comment: But it should work without it? Thanks. I wasn't aware of that interface so I my made similar for my own, for more dynamic cases, but there are many cons with such approach.

Comment: Well that’s nice but nothing else will see your changes.  Stick with the MS variety